# Handling Makefile dependencies in multiple subdirectories and outputting to seperate subdirectory

Tags: c++, makefile

I've been reading through posts about Makefiles that use subdirectories, but can't seem to put all the pieces together properly. I have the following file structure:

```
program
    |
    - src
    |
    - include
    | 
    - build
    |
    - bin
    |
    - Makefile
```

All my sources (.cpp) are in program/src/, all my headers (.hpp) are in program/include, I want all my object files and dependency files put into program/build, and I want my binary placed into program/bin. The following is what I currently have in my Makefile:

```
CXX = g++
BIN_DIR = bin
TARGET = $(BIN_DIR)/coreint
BUILD_DIR = build
SRC_DIR = src
INC_DIR = include
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -g

# Get all source files
SRCS := $(shell find $(SRC_DIR) -name *.cpp)
# Get all object files by replacing src directory with build directory    and replace extension
OBJS := $(subst $(SRC_DIR), $(BUILD_DIR), $(SRCS:%.cpp=%.o))
# Get all depend files by replacing extensions
DEPS := $(OBJS:.o=.d)
# Get all includes by searching include directory
INCS := $(shell find $(INC_DIR) -name *.hpp)
# Append -I to the front of each include
INCS := $(foreach d, $(INCS), -I$d)
# Using VPATH to find files in src/ include/ and build/
VPATH = $(SRC_DIR):$(INC_DIR):$(BUILD_DIR)

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $(TARGET)

# Build object files and put in build directory
$(BUILD_DIR)%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

# Place dependency files in build directory
# automatically generate dependency rules
$(BUILD_DIR)%.d: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -MF"$@" -MG -MM -MD -MP -MT"$@" -MT"$(OBJS)" "$<"
# -MF  write the generated dependency rule to a file
# -MG  assume missing headers will be generated and don't stop with an error
# -MM  generate dependency rule for prerequisite, skipping system headers
# -MP  add phony target for each header to prevent errors when header is missing
# -MT  add a target to the generated dependency

.PHONY: clean all

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(DEPS) $(TARGET)

-include $(DEPS)
```

When I run make, I get the following error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `build/assign.o', needed by `bin/coreint'.  Stop.
```

Where assign.o is the first file in the build directory. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Isn't there just missing slash after the `$(BUILD_DIR)`? AFAIK, the current code would generate rules like `buildassign.o: assign.cpp`

Comment: /me facepalms. That's all it was. I've been looking at this thing for over 4 hours this morning and you saw it right away. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was simply missing a '/' after my BUILD_DIR:

```
# Build object files and put in build directory
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```